# Rsyslog log all but not from port 80

Tags: linux, centos, rsyslog

I have a rsyslog server and now I need rsyslog to log everything from the Web server. But rsyslog shall not log things from what the websever recipient on port 80.
how do I do that?

I have configure the server. on the client to send everything to the log.

Comment: @Bib I have an assignment there I need to make a Rsyslog server to log everything from webserver except things from port 80

Comment: Welcome to SO! First off, to answer your question some more information is needed; What did you configure (provide config)? What did you try to solve your problem? Secondly, SO is a Q&A site for programming(-related) questions, your question seems to be more about installation/setup and therefore is probably better of on other SE sites, like [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask?tags=rsyslog).